# Calculation of amount to 10th of last month on 10th of this month

Tags: php

I have a little problem.

code:

```
$val = 0;   
if(date("Ymd", strtotime("tenth day of last month") )>= date('Ymd', strtotime($value['time'])) && date("Ymd", strtotime("tenth day of this month") ) <= date('Ymd', strtotime($value['time'])))         
    $val += $value['money'];
```

Tell me, what's wrong here?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: We don't know what you actually want. So, that might be the problem?

Comment: what is in `$value['money']` & `$value['time']` ??

Comment: $value['time'] - timestamp

Comment: -4, damnit. Nice community, bye, thanks.

Comment: @user2491101 don't give up! Just elaborate a little bit more :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `"tenth day of last month"` is not a valid `strtotime()` value. Do this instead:

```
date('Ym10', strtotime('last month'))
```

So your total code would be:

```
$val = 0;

$time = date('Ymd', strtotime($value['time']));
if (date("Ym10", strtotime("last month")) <= $time 
        && $time <= date("Ym10")) {
    $val += $value['money'];
}
```

Comment: I'm really grateful to you! Thanks!